# A method of deconstructing a number into its digits

Tags: matlab

Is it possible to take a number and get the value of each digit in MATLAB? In the end, I want to get each digit to be a character, so for example 101 would become `first = '1', second = '0', third = '1'`. I was thinking that this could be done using if statements and a logical AND, ie

`if number & 1 == 1
     third = '1'`

etc. But I can see that logical ANDs do not work this way in MATLAB. I am open to suggestions either like mine or something different that I am missing. If it is relevant, my numbers will always only have either 1s or 0s.

Comment: Just convert it to a string? see [`num2str`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html) for example

Comment: @Dan, I don't want to just convert it into a string, I want each digit to be its own string. So the number `101` will be turned into 3 variables, `'1'`, `'0'` and `'1'`.

Comment: Why each digit a different string? With `str = num2str(101);` you can then index `str(1)` (first digit), `str(2)` (second digit) etc. That's much easier than having separate variables

Comment: Its for a different part of my program. I have variables which are strings and I want to be able to compare those variables to the individual digits in another function. But your suggestion works for my needs! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can get this done without a for loop by substracting strings

```
number = 10156;
digits = num2str(number) - '0'
digits =

 1     0     1     5     6
```

Now `digits` is a vector, which elements are your digits as characters. I do not think it is a good idea to use one variable for each digit, and there is no elegant way of doing so. You will most likely do it manually

```
[first, second, third] = deal(z(1), z(2), z(3))
```

If your numbers may not only be positive integers (as i read it from your example), you can remove the sign by using the absolute value and remove the decimal point (see Divakars comment).

```
digits = strrep(num2str(abs(number)),'.','') - '0'
```

Also check Divakars comment for how to avoid deal - should you wish to.

Comment: `var1 = mat2cell(digits,1,ones(1,numel(digits)))` and then `[num1,num2,num3,num4,num5] = var1{:}` could be one way for storing into separate variables to avoid `deal`.

Comment: nice solution just tried it out and if you use -4.323 you get -3 4 -2 3 2 3 as result. It seems that minus sign is converted to -3 and the dot is converted to -2. Any idea why?

Comment: One hack way to process negative decimal numbers could be - `digits = strrep(num2str(abs(number)),'.','')-'0'`

Comment: @TheMinion That is because the minus is ``char(45)`` and zero is ``char(48)``. 45-48 equals -3. I didn't think of other inputs than positive integers. Divakars solution fits well so i added it to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

With `num2str` and its inverse, `str2num`, for example:

```
Number=1234;

NumberString=num2str(Number);

NumDigits=zeros(1,length(NumberString));

for ii=1:length(NumberString)

    NumDigits(ii)=str2num(NumberString(ii));

end
```

Result

```
NumDigits(3)

ans=3
```

Comment: Just read you want the digit to be a char, in that case just leave the str2num loop out :D

Comment: This nearly does the trick, but when I run it, 0 digits becomes 48, and 1s become 49. Why is this?

Comment: Yes, I see, you are reading your 'chars' as 'doubles', aren't you?

Comment: It works if with the str2num conversion, I think I hadn't refreshed my page. In that case, I'm getting a matrix of numbers. I also found this thread http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/246172It has other ways of also getting a matrix of numbers.